# Packaging a flask application with py2exe

Tags: python, flask, py2exe

I have a web application which uses Flask(python module) for the backend. I am trying to make it a standalone application using py2exe. [image: screenshot of the imports]

The setup.py code is

```
from setuptools import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['app.py'])
```

While packaging, the command prompt says that some of the modules are missing(missing modules mentioned in the prompt). How do I include those modules. While running this error shows up "No module named message":

[image: Error while running app.exe]

Can anybody tell what is that error because of??

Lets say if this .exe file is working properly at the end, I want to distribute this app on other systems. Do they need to install Flask or other modules??

Thanks